# Read and write value from active profile in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have some values in application-dev and application-qa properties. Now based on my active profile I would like to change the

```
 Properties props = new Properties();
 InputStream input = null;
 OutputStream output = null;
 
 try
        {


input = new FileInputStream("src\\main\\resources\\application-dev.properties");
 props.load(input);
 props.setProperty(key, value);
 output = new FileOutputStream("src\\main\\resources\\application-dev.properties");
 props.store(output, null);
        }
 catch(IOException ex)
        {
 ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I know that @Profile gives me my active profile but I am not very successful in fetching that value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good Evening Friend, have you tried using the following snippet:

```
@Value("${spring.profiles.active}")
private String activeProfiles;
```